# Jackson xml org.w3c.dom.Element property serialization

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

I have generated a set of java classes from a xsd schema through xjc.

A tag of the schema is

```
<xs:complexType name="SupplementaryDataEnvelope1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and xjc accordingly generates this property

```
@XmlAnyElement
protected Element any;
```

inside the SupplementaryDataEnvelope1 class

This part of the xml allows the inclusion of supplementary data that can be used by communities of users to add information to a message.
Just for test purpose I have included a small xml fragment that I have manually mapped to a pojo outside the xsd schema.

When I marshal the message using jaxb everything works fine.

```
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(document, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

This is the output

```
   <SplmtryData>
        <Envlp>
            <Context>
                <SessionId>12345</SessionId>
                <Language>IT</Language>
            </Context>
        </Envlp>
    </SplmtryData>
```

Then I try to do the same using Jackson

```
XmlMapper mapper = XmlMapper.xmlBuilder().defaultUseWrapper(false).build();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.registerModule(new JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule());
mapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true );
mapper.writeValue(writer, document);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Everything is correctly serialized, but the org.w3c.dom.Element property.

```
    <SplmtryData>
        <Envlp>
<any>&lt;Context>&lt;SessionId>12345&lt;/SessionId>&lt;Language>IT&lt;/Language>&#xd;
                &lt;/Context></any>
        </Envlp>
    </SplmtryData>
```

The first error is the erronoeous serialization of the "any" tag; secondly all "<" characters are printed as "<" (less than).

I have tried to annotate the property with com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue.

In this case Jackson correctly doesn't print the  tag, but instead of serializing the xml content, prints out the fully-qualified name of the correnspondent jaxb class:

com.fsajeva.rtp.iso.v10.pain013.SupplementaryDataEnvelope@427b5fb1

Am I missing any configuration?

P.S. I'm trying both Jaxb and Jackson serialization just for performance test purpose since the application should manage high volumes